# Static Connection method in Java

Tags: java, sql, static, connection

I'm confused regarding the use of static Connection to connect database. From what I've read, static connection shouldn't be used. This is my method:

```
private static Connection conn()
    {
        
        Connection connection = null;
            
        try {
            
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            connection = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
            

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        
        return connection;
        
    }
```

Then to get results a new method:

```
public void getResult(ArrayList test)
    {
        
        try
        {
            
            Connection conn = conn();
            
            String sql = "select id from test";
            
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next())
            {
                
               test.add(rs.getInt("id"));
                
            }
            
            conn.close();
            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
    }
```

Now, I don't know if this is safe. The connection is being started new every time method is called(?), and I' am closing it. Certainly connection pooling would be good for performance, but is this thread safe?

Comment: Technically it's threadsafe, but prone to connection leakage if an exception is thrown.  The `conn.close()` would not be called in that case.  The `conn.close()` should be in a finally block, or the code modified to use try-with-resources, which will call it implicitly.

Comment: Would that mean I could use it in a web app with finally block and it would still be thread safe?

Comment: Sorry, now I see that you already answered this. I want to mark your comment as answer.

Comment: I copied the information to an answer and added a little more detail to make it worth being an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it's threadsafe, but prone to connection leakage if an exception is thrown. The `conn.close()` would not be called in that case. The `conn.close()` should be in a finally block, or the code modified to use try-with-resources, which will call it implicitly.

The try-with-resources (Java 7+) allows declaration of variables that implement the `Autocloseable` interface in the try statement.  Those variables are then gracefully closed at the end of the `try` block.

```java
try( Connection conn = conn(); ) 
{
  //.... other statements
} catch(SQLException e) {
  //.... exception code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make use of a single connection that you can declare the `Connection object as private instance object` and always `check if it is null` before creating a new connection.

```
private Connection connection = null;
private static Connection conn()
{
    
    if ( connection == null) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");

      } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }

    }
    
    return connection;
}
```

---

```
public void getResult(ArrayList test)
{
    
    try
    {
        Connection conn = conn();
        
        String sql = "select id from test";
        
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        
        while(rs.next())
        {
            
           test.add(rs.getInt("id"));
            
        }
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
     finally{
       try {
         conn.close();
         conn = null;
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
         //Unable to close connection
       }
     }
    
}
```